# How to install Nexus 3 on Windows?

Tags: nexus

I downloaded an unpacked Sonatype Nexus OSS. But have no clue how to install it. There is a readme file. All tutorials get outdated.

`nexus.exe` just immediately finishes without a message. No logs appears. The same with `nexus.exe install` and `nexus.exe start` - URL `http://localhost:8081/` stays unavailable. There is no `jsw` directory anymore also.

My directory structure:

- D:\java\nexus\nexus-3.1.0-04
- D:\java\nexus\sonatype-work

Java:

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

Windows 7 x64

Comment: Using version 2.x is kinda workaround.

Comment: 2.x works...sad the latest release of nexus won't run without so much as a peep in the log file or console. suggestions on troubleshooting would be appreciated!

Comment: This should be a bug report! I shouldn't have to come to stackoverflow to work out how to run an application! How hard is it to make it respond to /? or --help or output to the console something when nothing is passed or even ship a readme with the dist???

Answer (score 30):

From starting version **3.x.x-xx**, navigate to **bin** directory ,run
`nexus.exe /run` and wait until you see the log message

```
 Started Nexus Repository Manager 3.x.x-xx
```

And then open the url `localhost:8081`. You will see the home-screen. To sign-in for full access, use the creditions `admin/admin123`. Further reading  [Installing and Running with the Distribution Archive](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/installation-methods) and [Accessing the User Interface](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/accessing-the-user-interface).

Comment: It's important to remember that you have to run the service with the correct permissions. On windows, if you want to install the service, you have to execute the command as an administrator.

Answer (score 12):

nexus /install

This will install nexus as a service. You can then open the user interface localhost:8081.

Default creds aare admin/admin123

Comment: Make sure that you're running the command as administrator on windows. This means opening the cmd.exe program as an administrator (right click and select the obvious option)

Comment: When you attempt to login the first time after installation, the login form will prompt you the password file for the 'admin' user. You can then login with that password and the first time login wizard will force you to change the password. Cheers!

Comment: first time login on fresh install:
username: `admin`
password: is located in admin.password file 
`sonatype-work\nexus3\admin.password`
it looks like it cant be changed on first sign-in. (ver.3.45)

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem in windows 10

open PowerShell go to your extracted place of your nexus oss bin folder

`.. \nexus-3.16.1-02-win64\nexus-3.16.1-02\bin`

and run your command like this

`.\nexus.exe /run`

it works and after a while tells

```
-------------------------------------------------

Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.16.1-02

-------------------------------------------------
```

now go to `http://localhost:8081`

Comment: Worked for me on Win10 and PowerShell!